# Specify SSH Port for Git

Tags: ssh, git

I use a non-standard ssh port (1234) for most of the servers I connect to.  So in my ssh config file I have:

```
Port 1234
```

But github.com uses port 22.  When I try to connect to github it obviously tries to use port 1234.  Right now I have to edit my ssh config to get things to work.

Here is a snippet from my git config:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:asdf/asdf.git
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just have a look at how to set up your *~/.ssh/config* file correctly (man 5 ssh_config). You can specify different settings for different hosts easily. To solve your problem you would set

```
Host github.com
Port 22
Host *
Port 1234
```

Do have a look at the ssh_config manual page, it explains everything you need to know on the first few pages.

Comment: This solution would not work if user needs to reach more than 1 port on same host.

Answer (score 50):

Setting up a section in `~/.ssh/config` is a fine solution, but it may be useful to know about another method.

The common *scp*-like syntax of `user@host:path` does not have a place for a port, but Git also supports an `ssh:` URL scheme that can be used to specify the port:

```
ssh://git@github.com:22/asdf/asdf.git
```

While an `ssh:` URL supports port specification, it does not support relative paths (e.g. there is no direct equivalent to the *scp*-like syntax of `user@host:path` where `path` does not start with a slash).

GitHub treats relative and absolute paths identically, so it works for them, but it may not work for all SSH-based Git repositories. For simple SSH-based hosting, you may need to insert `/home/username/` or `/Users/username/` when switching from relative to absolute paths. Some hosting systems may not handle absolute paths at all (though I would tend to call such lack of support a bug).

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I like this path best because it doesn't require mucking with my ssh config.  Thanks!

Comment: fyi, if the server has a "bare" repo then the connection string would look more like `ssh://git@github.com:22/asdf/asdf` (without the .git)

Comment: This doesn't work for all repo software types, though - some require a path component after the ":" without preceding them with "/" - in which case the ssh-config solution still works, but not this one.

Answer (score 6):

(Love it when I find the answer right after asking it.)

I modified my ssh config to specify the port for each host instead of being a global setting:

```
Host asdf.com
    Port 1234

Host github.com
    User git
    Hostname github.com
    Port 22
```

Answer (score 6):

Had a similar issue trying to connect to my git server

( have a [gitea](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-with-docker/) server in a docker container with ssh-port configured to `2022`, instead of standard 22, here as an example `my-git-server.lan` ).

1. create ssh key-pair (quiet, without password)

```
$ ssh-keygen -q -N '' -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/mykeyfile
```

(this will create two files: private-key `mykeyfile` and public-key `mykeyfile.pub`)

2. display contents of the public-key and copy/paste it to your profile's SSH keys in your git-server (similar to how you would do it on [Github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) )

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/mykeyfile.pub
```

3. add following lines to ssh-config to specify git-server's hostname, port and key-file

```
$ nano ~/.ssh/config
Host my-git-server.lan
  HostName my-git-server.lan
  User git
  Port 2022
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykeyfile
```

(notice that the username is **always** `git`, regardless of your actual username on your git-server)

4. test ssh connection to your git-server using public-key, .. and receive a success message

```
$ ssh -T git@my-git-server.lan
```

(again, notice that the username is **always** `git`)

5. specify your remote address `ssh://git@my-git-server.lan:2022/alex/myproject.git` for your local git repository (again, notice the user **git** and the port **2022**), .. check remote configuration

```
$ cd your/local/git/repository/folder
$ git remote add my-git-server ssh://git@my-git-server.lan:2022/alex/myproject.git
$ git remote -v
```

( here you also see that on my git-server my actual user is *alex* and repository is *myproject* )

Done! You can now work with your git-server .. fetch/commit/push etc.

Comment: After a lot of research I came across this answer, and this works for me, also even if I used only the IP address of the server where Gitea docker runs, since I haven't defined any other textual Hostname for it. I just put the IP address also as the HostName in the .ssh/config file (as I had configured in Gitea on the installation first page). This way I can clone also from the same machine where Gitea docker is running.

Answer (score 2):

Found this link, and although it was helpful my blog entry might help clarify it:

https://prestongarrison.com/change-port-git-is-using-for-ssh/

Basically i think its much better to just edit your .git/config file and make the changes.